# How to design microservices without leader election but job scheduling?

Tags: design, microservices

There is a microservices system that is currently using Zookeeper. Let's assume there is just one type of service `A` that exhibits a simple read of some value `t`. However, the one of existing A instances has scheduled task that updates `t` from time to time and its notify other through message bus that value has been changed.

I want pull everything back from Zookeeper and find a better way to do such job scheduling across multiple instances. I thought about getting a delayed queue that will send a message to just one of group and it will post another delayed message to exchange pipe. However, such implementation in RabbitMQ requires additional add-on and I am looking for something better.

Any ideas?

Comment: "Leader election" has to do with distributed computing.  Is that what you're doing here?  Perhaps you could provide a brief description of the problem scenario and your proposed architecture.